# .NET Framework 4.8 install failing and rolling back on Win Server 2016 Core Edition

Tags: .net, dotnet-framework

I'm unable to install .NET Framework 4.8 on a Windows Server 2016 Core Edition. Initial installation starts and gets to the point of:

> Installation completed successfully with success code: (0x80070BC2),
> "The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective
> until the system is rebooted.

Once the server reboots, the following is shown (I've separated into individual quote blocks because pasting in one is not easy on the eye):

> We couldn't complete the updates. Undoing changes. Don't turn off your computer

Looking at CBS.log I can see the following which looks to be the point at where the installation fails and rollback is initiated:

> New component: [l:130 ml:131]'NetFx4-_dataperfcounters_ini, Culture=neutral, Version=4.0.15744.161, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64'

> Installer name: 'LodCtr Installer'

> 2022-07-20 16:22:02, Error                 CSI    00000027 (F) Logged @2022/7/20:15:22:02.013 : [l:117 ml:118]'RegQueryValue_ServiceFirstCounter("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services",".NET Data Provider for SqlServer") fails (2,0)'
> [gle=0x80004005]

> 2022-07-20 16:22:02, Error                 CSI    00000028 (F) Logged @2022/7/20:15:22:02.044 : [l:62 ml:63]'CntrtextInstallPerfDll: Error 87 from CntrtextCreateObjectList'
> [gle=0x80004005]

> 2022-07-20 16:22:02, Error                 CSI    00000029 (F) Logged @2022/7/20:15:22:02.044 : [l:45 ml:46]'CntrtextInstallPerfDll: Returning status = 87'
> [gle=0x80004005]

> 2022-07-20 16:22:02, Error                 CSI    0000002a@2022/7/20:15:22:02.044 (F) CMIADAPTER: Inner Error Message from AI HRESULT = E_INVALIDARG
> ['The parameter is incorrect.'] [gle=0x80004005]

> 2022-07-20 16:22:02, Error                 CSI    0000002b@2022/7/20:15:22:02.044 (F) CMIADAPTER: AI failed. HRESULT = E_INVALIDARG
> Element:
> ''
> [gle=0x80004005]

> 2022-07-20 16:22:02, Error                 CSI    0000002c@2022/7/20:15:22:02.044 (F) CMIADAPTER: Exiting with HRESULT code = E_INVALIDARG.
> [gle=0x80004005]

> 2022-07-20 16:22:02, Error      [0x018015] CSI    0000002e (F) Failed execution of queue item Installer: LodCtr Installer ({d82eedee-854e-4f9a-b458-ae1bc62a0e6b}) with HRESULT E_INVALIDARG.  Failure will not be ignored: A rollback will be initiated after all the operations in the installer queue are completed; installer is reliable[gle=0x80004005]

I'm a little stumped with this one. Suggestions for LodCtr issues is to run the below:

```
lodctr /R
winmgmt.exe /RESYNCPERF
```

However, I've done that and rebooted but the same occurs on re-install attempts. I've even removed  .NET back to the standard 4.6 install provided by Windows Features.

I'm not seeing any other logs providing any relevant cause for this failure at the moment so appreciate any advice to troubleshoot the rollback cause further.